# What programming languages/platforms can you use for GUI in a WinPE environment?

Tags: windows, user-interface, programming-languages, winpe

I'm starting work on a project that must be delivered in [WinPE](http://perl-win32-gui.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/docs.cgi). I will likely be able to use WinPE 3.0. I'm also aware of [Bart's PE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) and [VistaPE](http://www.vistape.net/), but I think I'm going to stick with WinPE. I need x64 support and the full range of storage drivers.

I want to develop an app with a GUI and network access. I would like to work in Visual Studio to design my GUI, although that's not a requirement.

What programming languages will I be able to use to target WinPE, with GUI support? With a little bit of research I've discovered that .NET simply isn't supported (by Microsoft), so that seems to exclude all C#, modern VB, etc. Has anyone run Java/Swing? C++ with MFC or ATL (modern)? Hacked in .NET to get CLR support?

---

I can run Perl with [Win32::GUI.](http://perl-win32-gui.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/docs.cgi) But it does not allow me to use Visual Studio with the Resource View to create the GUI I want. It must all be done programmatically. Or is that possible?

Comment: I wish I had seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589387/developing-lightweight-no-runtime-windows-based-gui-applications-using-free-too/589436) related StackOverflow question.

Comment: WinPE 4 now supports .NET 4.0 Client Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try Realbasic, the program will compile its own local dll. I've used it to create a front loader for PE via PXE. Realbasic is cross-platform windows/mac/linux. You will want the professional version, but it's been worth the cost at my company.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mono and C#, but it makes WinPE MUCH larger.  I'm told you can use mkbundle to keep it more reasonable.

I personally use Borland Delphi (v7 and prior, not sure if turbo works or not).

Answer (score 0):

You can use .NET now, starting with WinPE 4.0 http://www.deploymentresearch.com/Blog/tabid/62/EntryId/41/Windows-8-Preview-Howto-Creating-a-WinPE-boot-image-with-NET-Framework-and-PowerShell.aspx